# Matlab - Callback Function of a serial port that dont know the reference

Tags: matlab

Hello I'm using a library of thinkgear to connect by bluetooth a mindwave with matlab but I need to stablish a callback function of the serial port but I dont have a reference of that port.Is there anyway I could do it? I dont want to do any loop like the code: This is the code

```
portnum1 = 5;   %COM Port #
comPortName1 = sprintf('\\\\.\\COM%d', portnum1);


% Baud rate for use with TG_Connect() and TG_SetBaudrate().
TG_BAUD_57600 =      57600;


% Data format for use with TG_Connect() and TG_SetDataFormat().
TG_STREAM_PACKETS =     0;


% Data type that can be requested from TG_GetValue().
TG_DATA_RAW =         4;

%load thinkgear dll
loadlibrary('Thinkgear.dll');
fprintf('Thinkgear.dll loaded\n');

%get dll version
dllVersion = calllib('Thinkgear', 'TG_GetDriverVersion');
fprintf('ThinkGear DLL version: %d\n', dllVersion );


%%
% Get a connection ID handle to ThinkGear
connectionId1 = calllib('Thinkgear', 'TG_GetNewConnectionId');
if ( connectionId1 < 0 )
    error( sprintf( 'ERROR: TG_GetNewConnectionId() returned %d.\n', connectionId1 ) );
end;

% Set/open stream (raw bytes) log file for connection
errCode = calllib('Thinkgear', 'TG_SetStreamLog', connectionId1, 'streamLog.txt' );
if( errCode < 0 )
    error( sprintf( 'ERROR: TG_SetStreamLog() returned %d.\n', errCode ) );
end;

% Set/open data (ThinkGear values) log file for connection
errCode = calllib('Thinkgear', 'TG_SetDataLog', connectionId1, 'dataLog.txt' );
if( errCode < 0 )
    error( sprintf( 'ERROR: TG_SetDataLog() returned %d.\n', errCode ) );
end;

% Attempt to connect the connection ID handle to serial port "COM3"
errCode = calllib('Thinkgear', 'TG_Connect',  connectionId1,comPortName1,TG_BAUD_57600,TG_STREAM_PACKETS );
if ( errCode < 0 )
    error( sprintf( 'ERROR: TG_Connect() returned %d.\n', errCode ) );
end

fprintf( 'Connected.  Reading Packets...\n' );




%%
%record data

j = 0;
i = 0;
while (i < 102400)   %loop for 20 seconds
    if (calllib('Thinkgear','TG_ReadPackets',connectionId1,1) == 1)   %if a packet was read...

        if (calllib('Thinkgear','TG_GetValueStatus',connectionId1,TG_DATA_RAW) ~= 0)   %if RAW has been updated 
            j = j + 1;
            i = i + 1;
            data(j) = calllib('Thinkgear','TG_GetValue',connectionId1,TG_DATA_RAW);
        end
    end

    if (j == 256)
        plotRAW(data);            %plot the data, update every .5 seconds (256 points)
        j = 0;
    end

end





%disconnect             
calllib('Thinkgear', 'TG_FreeConnection', connectionId1 );
```

Comment: What do you mean by "you don't have a reference".  You don't know which port is being used?

Comment: I know its port 5, but with a Matlab callback I need the SerialPort Variable